# Calling a Python function from HTML is not working

Tags: python, html, flask

In my HTML page, I have a button. When I click on the button it should call a Python function that takes a screenshot and save it in the same directory. I tried my Python method and it is working correctly on local. But when I used Flask to call the function from a HTML button, it does nothing and there are no errors. How to get the screenshot image ?

```
Python Flask:
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# Function to take the screenshot and save it
def takesc():
    with mss() as sct:
        sct.shot()

@app.route('/takeScreenshot')
def takeScreenshot():
    return takesc()
```

My HTML

```
<button onclick="{{ takeScreenshot }}">ScreenShoot</button>
```

I also tried to use '`url_for`' as following, but still nothing happened:

```
<button onclick="{{ url_for('takeScreenshot') }}">ScreenShoot</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a button, it is shorter use an `href`:

```
<a href='/takeScreenshot' class='my_button_class'>ScreenShoot</a>
```

You can then use css to add style under the `.my_button_class` class.

However, to use a button, you need to specify the redirect:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{url_for( 'takeScreenshot') }}';">Display Table Y</button>
```

Also, `takeScreenshot` is not returning text to be rendered on the screen. `takesc` does not return anything, thus, it should be called before the route returns a response:

```
@app.route('/takeScreenshot')
def takeScreenshot():
   takesc()
   return "screen shot saved"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. If you do not mind would you please tell me why I cannot use a button or what is the difference ? Also after clicking the link, the screenshot is taken but the execution ends and gives me this error 'ValueError: View function did not return a response'

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a life saver! Instead of returning "Screenshot saved" I return render("index.html") so that it does not take me to another page. Thanks again man!!!